# Pycurl to Jira json

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, http-auth

I'm trying to get json from jira but all the time receive empty response.
By the way from browser I get data well.

Here is my server code:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
buffer = StringIO()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://jirawebsite.com/file.json')
c.setopt(c.HTTPAUTH, c.HTTPAUTH_BASIC)
c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

Yes, status code is **200**. Response cookie contain **HttpOnly** (don't know if it's important)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the Python Library for Jira, will make your life a lot easier!

[Python library for interacting with JIRA via REST APIs.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira/)

Also, consuming any REST from Python the Requests library is a lot more simple to work with.

[Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: @ВласБоюс, did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using Requests due to it having a major bug with verifying security so if this is only for jira, maybe, but if you're going to continue to develop scripts for anything else then Requests completely fails.

Comment: Can you add more details by referencing relevant links etc., Your answer is more likely to attract downvotes. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to write good answers